# user search engine with tags - Django - Python

Tags: python, django

I want to make a user search engine with profile tags. The search engine will show users and tags

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = None
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/profile_pictures/', default='uploads/profile_pictures/default.png', blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='followers')
    tag_i = TagsField(max_length=1000, default='non')
```

TagsField is from django-tagify

views.py

```
class UserSearch(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('query')
        profile_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(tag_i__icontains=query) | Q(user__username__icontains=query))
        field_name = 'tag_i'
        obj = UserProfile.objects.first()
        field_object = UserProfile._meta.get_field(field_name)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_objects(obj)
        field_value = "".join(field_value)
        field_value = field_value.split(",")


    context = {
        'profile_list': profile_list,
        "tags": field_value,
    }
```

the current code assigns the same tags to everyone. How to assign tags to each person?

what should I use instead..

```
        obj = UserProfile.objects.first()
```

to make tags suitable for individual users

Comment: Where does this TagsField come from ? if you want to connect more than one tags with profile you can make your custom Tag model and add m2m field with User profile

Comment: thank's for anwser. TagsField is from django-tagify

Comment: "the current code assigns the same tags to everyone. How to assign tags to each person?" 

Do you mean currently authorized person? You can use ```request.user.profile.tag_i``` to do that.  You should not change user's tags in a get request, add a POST request handler where you change the user's tags. There is no problem in filtering the tags?

Comment: Thank's for answer. No i don't need request user. I want just display in search results. nick and tags.

Comment: I tried to take the values directly like this `tags = UserProfile.tag_i` but i get error `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019015F36BB0>`